# MySQL check in PHP where value is equal to x and y is not empty

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to to a check in my database where username=$username and where the name field isn't empty. I'm not sure how to do this, so I am open for some input on this. :)

---

**PHP CODE:**

```
$isinuse_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND (name IS NOT NULL OR name<>''");
if(mysql_num_rows($isinuse_sql) != 0) {
    $isinuse_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($isinuse_sql);
    $isinuse = $isinuse_row['name'];
    echo "1";
} else {
    echo "0";
}
```

Comment: why you are using `AND (name IS NOT NULL OR name<>`...`username = $username` is sufficient

Comment: Looks alright to me. What is the problem when you run it? Oh and stop using mysql, it is DEPRECATED and has been marked as such in the manual for years. Use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Hopefully you escape you data in `$username`, to prevent SQL Injection.

Comment: @Shotgun, Yes, I use escape string. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as `NULL` value is interpreted as a false you can check value of name like

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND users.name<>''
```

use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) instead of sql query as it is deprecated like David Soussan said

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$username = 'a';
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND users.name<>''";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);


$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

print_r($row);
mysqli_close($con);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND (name IS NOT NULL AND name!='')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh I see now, silly me. If it is an empty string it is not null so you get true with an OR when you want false.

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND name IS NOT NULL AND name<>''"
```

Comment: I tried your code here, and it did just return 0...... don't understand this... :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND IFNULL(name, '') != '' "
```